Unitary transformation of the momentum operator in quantum mechanics
I'm currently reviewing some lecture notes on unitary transformations and I'm having trouble understanding a particular calculation.
The Hamiltonian is given as
$$\hat H(t) = \frac{\left[\hat{\mathbf{p}} - q \mathbf{A}(\hat{\mathbf{r}})\right]^2}{2m} +q\Phi(\hat{\mathbf{r}})$$
The unitary transformation is given as
$$\hat U_0 = \exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar}q \chi(\hat{\mathbf{r}}, t)\right] . $$
We know that this is true for our transformed Hamiltonian:
$$\hat H' = \hat U_0^\dagger \hat H \hat U_0 - i \hbar \hat U_0^\dagger \hat U_0$$
In order to obtain a result, we take a look at the transformation of the momentum operator
$$\hat{U}_0^\dagger \hat{\mathbf{p}} \hat{U}_0 = \hat{U}_0^\dagger \hat{\mathbf{p}} \hat{U}_0 + \hat{U}_0^\dagger \hat{U}_0 \hat{\mathbf{p}} - \hat{U}_0^\dagger \hat{U}_0 \hat{\mathbf{p}} = \hat{U}_0^\dagger \hat{U}_0 \hat{\mathbf{p}} + \hat{U}_0^\dagger [\hat{\mathbf{p}}, \hat{U}_0]$$
Now we were told that the commutator is
$$[\hat{\mathbf{p}}, \hat{U}_0] = - i\hbar \nabla_{\mathbf{r}} U_0$$
but I don't really understand why that is the case. Is there someone who could help me understand how this commutator is evaluated?

Work in the coordinate representation,
$$\hat O(\hat{\mathbf{r}},\hat{\mathbf{p}} )  =\int\!\! d{\mathbf{r}}~~ |{\mathbf{r}}\rangle    O( {\mathbf{r}}, -i\hbar  \nabla_{\mathbf{r}}  ) \langle\mathbf{r}| ,$$
so, then,
$$[\hat{\mathbf{p}}, \hat{U}_0] \mapsto -i\hbar {U}_0( {U}_0^\dagger \nabla_{\mathbf{r}} U_0 -\nabla_{\mathbf{r}}) = -i\hbar (\nabla_{\mathbf{r}} U_0). 
$$
